# Sequelize authenticate() does not return any result

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using Sequelize with postgres database.
But authenticate() function does not send any response(whether it is success or failed)
Here is my code.

```
const connection = new Sequelize('BLIG', 'postgres', 'admin', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    define: {
        timestamps: false
    }
});

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.clear();
    connection.authenticate()
        .then(
            () => { console.log("Database connected..."), next() },
            error=>{console.log("Database connection error",error)}
        )
        .catch(err => { console.log('database connection error', err), res.redirect('/error') });
})
```

If anyone knows this issue, help me please.

Answer (score 5):

update your "pg" node package to 8.5.1 or above version using

```
npm i pg@8.5.1
```

Comment: Thank you, ffs I was sitting here for HOURS wondering why I couldn't connect. Cheers